# Universal Image Loader loading half images or partial images

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image loader library in my application. I am getting a strange problem that sometimes on some Android Mobile Phones it loads only HALF Images, like I have attached the image with.

Here is my configuration:

```
public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {

        // This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you
        // may tune some of them,
        // or you can create default configuration by
        // ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
        // method.
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                context)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1)
                .threadPoolSize(3)
                // default
                // .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .discCache(

                        new FileCountLimitedDiscCache(new File(
                                Constant.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PATH_FOR_LAZY), 100))
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
                // discCache(new TotalSizeLimitedDiscCache(new
                // File(Constant.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PATH_LAZY), 10))
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
                .discCacheFileCount(100)
                // .discCacheSize(1 * 512 * 1024)
                .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use a less descriptive config? (remove all your overrides that set the cache size, etc and then initialize it). Are you also sure that the images are not corrupt? Another thing to check is whether or not it respects the  `exif` parameters. Try setting considerExif (or something similar) and see if that helps.

Comment: If I use less descriptive config, then also the result is the same.

Comment: Can you paste your layout xml containing the image view? The problem may be there and not with the image loader. Also try to save down the image in the SD card location (before you load it through the UIL) and have a look at it in the gallery to make sure the image itself is not corrupt.

Comment: Rather I have noticed the problem may of be of decoding Bitmaps

Comment: Sounds like a decoding problem. Is the image displayed correct in your web browser (if you open the url)? Did you clean the cache?

Comment: its working fine in other conditions, but when I switched network contineously, i met with this problem.

Comment: How about using the Picasso library from square?

Comment: Yes use Picasso much easier to use and has tons of wonderful features that are easy to customise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Compile this dependency: `compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'`
2. Modify your adapter or imageview like:

this

```
Ion.with(imageView)
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
.error(R.drawable.error_image)
.animateLoad(spinAnimation)
.animateIn(fadeInAnimation)
.load("http://example.com/image.png");
```

Based on this [example](https://github.com/koush/ion)

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). I am use this instead of UIL and recommend to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use listener while downloading images, in that listener you can do your work in `onLoadingComplete()`.

Here is the sample code for this:

```
imageLoader.loadImage(url, new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                        Bitmap loadedImage) {
                super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);

                    //write your code here to use loadedImage
                }

            });
```

This code will help you to identify when image is completely downloaded.